# Python bullet bindings

Tags: ros, python, bullet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know if there are python bindings for bullet?

I stumbled upon the bullet_python package http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=bullet_python, but I couldn't quite figure out how to install it.  I am running ROS-Diamondback on 64-bit Ubuntu Lucid 10.04.

Thanks,
--Will

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9492/python-bullet-bindings/) by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) on 2011-03-21**:
Although, not python bindings for bullet...  I did stumble across PyEuclid http://code.google.com/p/pyeuclid/ which seems to meet the modest vector transformation needs that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That was an experiment in exposing bullet's API in python using SWIG.  It was developed against boxturtle and won't work with diamondback without significant conversion.  To get it you will have to check it out from svn.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) on 2011-03-21**:
Thanks.  My problems with bullet_python were more with how to compile it, but now I see that it won't work with diamondback, I'll just move on.